# How to change Docker default subnet size?

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I wonder if there is any way to affect default subnet size and pool of addresses used when creating network without any parameters.

Steps to reproduce a problem:
1) Get a fresh VM with Docker (Ubuntu 16.04, Docker 1.12.3 in my case)
2) attempt to create 50 networks:

```
  for i in {1..50}; do docker network create net-$i; done
```

at some point you will start getting errors
3) see the results:

```
for i in $(docker network ls -q); do docker network inspect --format='{{.Name}} {{.IPAM.Config}}' $i; done
```

Output looks like:

```
net-1 [{172.18.0.0/16  172.18.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-2 [{172.19.0.0/16  172.19.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-3 [{172.20.0.0/16  172.20.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-4 [{172.21.0.0/16  172.21.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-5 [{172.22.0.0/16  172.22.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-6 [{172.23.0.0/16  172.23.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-7 [{172.24.0.0/16  172.24.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-8 [{172.25.0.0/16  172.25.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-9 [{172.26.0.0/16  172.26.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-10 [{172.27.0.0/16  172.27.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-11 [{172.28.0.0/16  172.28.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-12 [{172.29.0.0/16  172.29.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-13 [{172.30.0.0/16  172.30.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-14 [{172.31.0.0/16  172.31.0.1/16 map[]}]
net-15 [{192.168.0.0/20  192.168.0.1/20 map[]}]
net-16 [{192.168.16.0/20  192.168.16.1/20 map[]}]
net-17 [{192.168.32.0/20  192.168.32.1/20 map[]}]
net-18 [{192.168.48.0/20  192.168.48.1/20 map[]}]
net-19 [{192.168.64.0/20  192.168.64.1/20 map[]}]
net-20 [{192.168.80.0/20  192.168.80.1/20 map[]}]
net-21 [{192.168.96.0/20  192.168.96.1/20 map[]}]
net-22 [{192.168.112.0/20  192.168.112.1/20 map[]}]
net-23 [{192.168.128.0/20  192.168.128.1/20 map[]}]
net-24 [{192.168.144.0/20  192.168.144.1/20 map[]}]
net-25 [{192.168.160.0/20  192.168.160.1/20 map[]}]
net-26 [{192.168.176.0/20  192.168.176.1/20 map[]}]
net-27 [{192.168.192.0/20  192.168.192.1/20 map[]}]
net-28 [{192.168.208.0/20  192.168.208.1/20 map[]}]
net-29 [{192.168.224.0/20  192.168.224.1/20 map[]}]
net-30 [{192.168.240.0/20  192.168.240.1/20 map[]}]
```

So Docker uses RFC1918 networks 172.16/12 and 192.168/16 with network masks that would divide both networks into 16 subnets.

I wonder if there is any way to affect this behavour.
I use docker-compose in my CI pipeline to deploy apps and I strongly want to avoid hardcoding networks in docker-compose.yml files, since it will ruin it's portability.

Comment: Refer `ipam` section under https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/network-configuration-reference. It might help.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm trying to aviod, since it makes compose-files unportable. I was hoping for some Docker daemon options like here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/
It has options to change docker0's IP address and to change pool for containers' IPs but not pool for created networks.

Comment: There's a [feature request](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21776), but no movement on it. Sign the "petition," so to speak.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it will be available when `docker-ce` `v18.06` lands, you will be able to edit the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` daemon settings with the following line:

`{
  "default-address-pools":[
    {"base":"172.80.0.0/16","size":24}, {"base":"172.90.0.0/16","size":24}
  ]
}`

See the [Merged PR#36396 on GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36396) for more information.

Comment: Took only 1.5 years to implement this, thanks for notification :)

Comment: Please note that only 172.16.0.0/12 (range 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.0.0) is available for private allocation. So your examples will cause hard-to-diagnose trouble when trying to communicate with legitimate public IP addresses.

Comment: Exactly, and the opposite also is true. Anybody coming from internet from 172.80.0.x will not be able to connect to your server.